# Swap all images on page via one link JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, swap

I have to build a site that has multiple color options but it also has to have the ability to give the 'Zoom' impression. This is why I need all images on page so I am able to increase their size.

The only problem I have is I am not sure how to add a certain prefix to all images on the page via one link.

E.G. Click Pink/White and it adds a prefix _pw to all images on the page..

Any help would be great

Comment: add a prefix to all images?  change the style to all images? change the sources of the images?

Comment: yes add a prefix to the image itself e.g. images/banner_pw.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solutions posted so far work, but are horribly inefficient. Here’s a better solution:

```
var isZoom = false;
$('#some-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('img').each(function() {
    this.src = isZoom ? this.src.replace('_pw.jpg', '.jpg') : this.src.replace('.jpg', '_pw.jpg');
  });
  isZoom = !isZoom;
});
```

This assumes that all images have the same `.jpg` extension.

Alternatively, you could use `.attr` instead of `.each`:

```
var isZoom = false;
$('#some-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return isZoom ? src.replace('_pw.jpg', '.jpg') : src.replace('.jpg', '_pw.jpg');
  });
  isZoom = !isZoom;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this works perfect, but when I click the link again it breaks the images, is there a way to if they click it remove the prefix?

Comment: `    this.src = isZoom ? this.src.replace('_pw.jpg', '.jpg') : this.src = this.src.replace('.jpg', '_pw.jpg');` this looks wonky to mee.

Comment: I sorted the adding prefix via the href myself, just having problems removing the _pw with the 2nd click working

Comment: @mannaz @john There was a typo, the `this.src` shouldn’t be there of course. Edited my answer.

Comment: > but are horribly inefficient
Why?

Comment: @marcosfromero: I left a comment with an example on your answer. You’ve already changed it now, much better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get all your zoomable images (maybe with some special class to identify them)
// Iterate over them
$('img.specialClass').each(function() {

    // Get original src attribute
    var origSrc = this.src; 

    // Split by slash
    var arraySrc = origSrc.split('/'); 

    // New src attribute is:
    var newSrc = arraySrc.slice(0,-1).join('/') + // all but last parts of URL
    '/pw_' + // with a new prefix
    arraySrc.slice(-1); // and the original file name

    // Finally, set the new src attribute
    this.src = newSrc;
})
```

Comment: Use `this.src` instead of `$(this).attr('src')` and `this.src = newSrc` instead of `$(this).attr('src', newSrc)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('IMG').attr('class','_pw');
```

Should set all IMG's classnames to "_pw".

i.e:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
   $('IMG').attr('class','_pw');
});
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake with explaining I need to to add the prefix to the image itself E.G. images/banner_pw.jpg

Comment: `jQuery#onclick` is not defined, so your second example won’t work at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more concise way of writing it, but it's a simple operation nonetheless:

```
 $('#pinkButton').click(function()
 {
      $('img').each(function()
      {
           $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src') + '_pw');
           // Will take the previous src attribute and add '_pw' in the end.
      });
 });
```

There will probably need to be some modification to the above to put the suffix in the right spot of the src string, but you get the idea. (basically, making sure the extension gets moved, etc)

Comment: You forgot to prevent the default action of the click event. Also, you’re instantiating two new jQuery objects inside the `each`, while none are needed. That’s a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").attr('src', function(i,a) {
    return a + '_pw';
});
```